# How does FTP work

Tags: ftp, ftp-server

I want to make my own ftp server software. I know, there are many ftp servers ready to install that have many features, but I still want to make my own, cause I can customize it and make it the way I want. Also, I find it fun to code, and I would rather make my own FTP server instead of downloading one that is ready to use if I have time. The problem is I can't find any information on how the protocol works and stuff like that. I would appreciate it if someone could explain how the protocol works or at least send me to a page that has useful information. Thanks!

Comment: I would highly recommend against this, the homebrew software you are going to cook up with you very limited understanding of FTP is going to be highly unsecure and easily exploitable by a hostile actor. Please do not do this.

Comment: start from here: [HPServer](http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7860&lngWId=1) and here: [NewsServer - A great tutorial that explains how to implement your own protocols (like HTTP and FTP)](http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=45203&lngW)

Answer (score 0):

If you are curious about beeing downvoted, here the explanation:

When planning a homebrew ftp program, it is a good point to google about FTP. Soon you will find RFC`S (that is "Request For Comment"), where things like the FTP protocol are described.

Thats a good starting point.

Then, when you have troubles with specific points, come back, show your code here, and ask for help.

Comment: I didn't find anything on Google. I remember a while ago, I found something really useful, but I can't find it now. I guess I'm unlucky or I'm not searching for the right thing.

Comment: start with "ftp protocol specification"

Comment: and if you search for "ftp protocol source code" you will find even SO entries.